# My computer network interface is crashing while downloading

Tags: windows-10, internet, crash, download, network-adapter

As title says my computer network interface is crashing while downloading.

I'm on `Windows 10`. My motherboard is `asus p8h77-m pro`.

I can use my computer and internet as normal, I never experienced this problem before, sometimes "micro crash" but once a month and seconds... but now I have a best connection, I had 10mbps and now 600mbps.

The moment I start a download, seconds after, my network crash, but it's not my home internet because I can still use internet in other devices I tested that. Then if I wait some seconds the internet comes back, and eventually crash again.

I need help to try to fix this problem or try to see what's going on but I don't know where to start.

FIXED: I bought a new computer.

Comment: What do you mean by "crash" details please.

Comment: @Moab I mean it stop working, some times I see the icon of "no internet connection" sometimes is too "short" the disonnection that the icon doesn't appear and remains "normal" icon in the toolbar

Comment: (1) Is the situation that despite having a faster connection you are unable to download large files? (2) Did this problem appear immediately after you changed internet plans? (3) Did you also change your ISP? (4) Did you change modem and did you receive it from the ISP and what's its exact model? (5) Did you contact the Support of your ISP with the problem?

Comment: Hi @harrymc 
1) I can download large files bc the downloader like Steam can retake the download.
2) Yes, indeed.
3) Same ISP.
4) Yes I got a new router because I switched from DSL to optical fiber.
5) Not yet because this only happens to 1 computer I have, my computer.

Comment: Did you try the network troubleshooting function of Windows? Sounds to me like a duplex, speed or MTU mismatch between router and PC.

Comment: I'm going to test today both solutions in afternoon, when I get home after work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If other computers don't have this problem, it seems like there is some incompatibility
of your computer with the new router.

The possibilities are vast, so here is some general advice:

- Search for a driver update to your network adapter and perhaps for the
  modem's firmware
- Check the settings of the modem for anything that may affect your computer
- Ask the Support of your ISP if it would be safe to factory reset the modem
  (or for any other advice)
- Try another USB external network adapter, to see if the problem is limited
  only to your adapter.

Comment: As you mention the last point, I tested my wireless usb adapter and everything was smooth, but not high speed because of limitations. Is there a possibility that I can track the network adapter actions like if it has errors, like icq, service disconnection ? but now I'm gonna search for the driver.

Comment: I'm going to test today both solutions in afternoon, when I get home after work.

Comment: Everything is updated and settings are ok

Comment: Does your ISP have an explanation? You could for example ask to replace the modem by a better model.

Comment: I bought a new computer amd ryzen 9 with x570 motherboard, and of course my internet is like lightspeed with 0 issues.

Answer (score 1):

[Network_Diagnostics.vbs](https://pastebin.com/aqA6fJ2M)

I made a vbscript that can create a shortcut on your desktop with a HotKey `Ctrl+Alt+D` in order to run the Network Diagnostics when you have an issue with your connection and try to fix it !

Just copy and paste this code in your notepad and save it as `Network_Diagnostics.vbs` and execute it by double click to create the shortcut !

---

```
Option Explicit
' Vbscript Created by Hackoo on 09/06/2020 @16:00
' Tested only on Windows 10 (32 bits)
' Updated on 10/06/2020 for testing the Hotkey after creating the shortcut on the desktop 
Dim Title : Title = "Shortcut Creator for Network Diagnostics by Hackoo 2020"
' We call the subroutine Create_Shortcut in order to create it on the desktop
Call Create_Shortcut(_
    "NetworkDiagnostics",_
    "%SystemRoot%\system32\msdt.exe",_
    "-skip TRUE -path %Windir%\diagnostics\system\networking -ep NetworkDiagnosticsPNI",_
    "%SystemRoot%\system32\msdt.exe,0",_
    "Network Diagnostics to fix problems",_
    "CTRL+ALT+D"_
)
 ' Showing a Message Box with three languages : English,French and Arabic
MsgBox "The shortcut was created successfully on your desktop !" & vbCrlf &_
"Le raccourci a été créé avec succès sur votre bureau !" & vbcrlf &_
"تم إنشاء الاختصار بنجاح على سطح المكتب الخاص بك !",vbInformation,Title
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Just for testing the Hotkey after creating the shortcut on the desktop :
' To send keyboard characters that are comprised of a regular keystroke in combination with a SHIFT, CTRL, or ALT,
' create a compound string argument that represents the keystroke combination.
' You do this by preceding the regular keystroke with one or more of the following special characters :
' Key   ===> Special Character
' SHIFT ===> +
' CTRL  ===> ^
' ALT   ===> %
' For further reading about sendkeys : https://www.vbsedit.com/html/4b032417-ebda-4d30-88a4-2b56c24affdd.asp
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Sendkeys "^%{d}"
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Create_Shortcut(ShortcutName,TargetPath,Arguments,IconLocation,Description,HotKey)
    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = chr(34) & TargetPath & chr(34)
    objShortCut.Arguments = Arguments
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = IconLocation
    ObjShortCut.Description = Description
    ObjShortCut.HotKey= HotKey
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And Refer to this on Stackoverflow question [VBS Check internet and delay script until ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576031/vbs-check-internet-and-delay-script-until-ready?answertab=active#tab-top)

I make another one today (26/08/2020) but in `.hta` not in `.vbs` you can give a try

[Check_Internet_Connection.hta](https://pastebin.com/yyewJYwW)

Comment: Thank you, I will try as soon as possible!

Comment: I tried this but never get a fix, just loaded the manager and I got Windows recomendations, but never fix. The hta script looks funny anyway.

Comment: I bought a new computer amd ryzen 9 with x570 motherboard, and of course my internet is like lightspeed with 0 issues.